# Would I be able to turn my internship into a full time job if I offered myself for minimum wage

Tags: negotiation

I love all aspects of where I'm working, and my employer seems to really like me, however I am currently an intern set to leave on June 15, 2017. I've been told that my employment likely won't be full time due to budget constraints, but I'd be willing to work for minimum wage (or less if it were possible, seriously that's how good of a job it is). If I told my employer that I'd be willing to work for such a low amount of pay for, let's say "experience", what are my chances of becoming a full time employee?

I think the full time employees that do the same thing I do make around $30/hr. I'm not joking about the experience though, I am trying to become a web developer and am currently at the stage where I have enough experience to do the work properly, however nobody will hire me as a full time employee. I'm currently making $15 an hour as an intern.

(I live in Alberta, Canada. Min wage is $12.20/hr. I have financial support through my girlfriend, combined with low monthly bills, so minimum wage is adequate pay for me.)

Comment: Why not just talk to your employer? They can tell you right away. We hae no idea if they'll be able to afford minimum wage.

Comment: @aresphobos I would absolute NOT tell them you'd work for minimum wage. First of all, you won't earn enough to support yourself and will probably need government assistance programs. On top of that, accepting minimum wage for experience could cause you to stay **underpaid** for years after you've gained experience! Your future employers will ask "what was your salary at your most recent job?" and when you say minimum wage it will automatically send red flags. No explanation will help. You need to realize that your current wage WILL affect your future wages.

Comment: Consider this when asking for minimum wage: [1] You come off as desperate. Companies will take advantage of you. [2] If they agree, you should not expect to be compensated at a fair market rate since it is unlikely they will give you a 200% or 300% raise. Maybe if you do good work you'll get a 10% or 20%, but your raise will not be worth your time. You'll look for a new job and do well in interviews. Maybe a company wants to hire you and they ask you what your current/last salary is. They will get it out of you or your employer. They will lowball you too. And so the cycle will continue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk to the employer. What can it hurt, you're already on the way out and the worst they can say is No.

That said, as I heard a long time ago, don't devalue yourself. If you offer yourself at too low a price, they won't take you seriously as a person who wants to work. As a general rule, the companies that I've worked for were leery of someone offering a less-than-average wage. This is because a person who works for less than standard is, in general, more likely to move on to another company for more wage later down the line. You're not going to be happy making $20 when your mate makes $35 for the same job.

If you want to work for the company, really really, then you should tell them that. "I realize you likely can't hire me on at the moment, but I would like you to keep me in mind if and when you do start hiring again, and let me know. Who knows, I could be in a dead-end job elsewhere that I would be more than willing to jump to your team, where I already know I'm useful and valued!"

Remember, you're an asset to whomever you work for. Treat yourself like one.